# What is export in js

Tags: javascript, import, export

`export default x` looks like defining a constant under dom to me in JavaScript. So is there a fundamental difference between a global variable or exported variable? A global variable is immediately available although you need to import an exported variable. Can you explain what is export and import in this sense?

Answer (score 0):

export what going to be exposed to whatever is importing.

I think you can have a look at
https://javascript.info/modules-intro
to get the idea

//  sayHi.js

```
export function sayHi(user) {
  alert(`Hello, ${user}!`);
}
```

//  main.js

```
import {sayHi} from './sayHi.js';

alert(sayHi); // function...
sayHi('John'); // Hello, John!
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you will import `sayHi` as `saySomething`. It is just used if you don't wont to specify exported name.

```
//  sayHi.js

export default function sayHi(user) {
  alert(`Hello, ${user}!`);
}

export function sayAnotherHi(user) {
  alert(`Hello, ${user}!`);
}
```

```
//  main.js

import saySomething, { sayAnotherHi } from './sayHi.js';
sayHi('John'); // Hello, John!
```

Another example could be jquery, when you import it, it imports like `import $ from "jquery"`, but inside, jquery exports `export default _jQuery`